# iOS- Nothing shows in Image Array (Swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, image, scrollview

I'm attempting to assign an Image to the array, then display the image- however, it doesn't show up. As you can see, after I assign the image to the array like this-

```
self.imageArray.append(UIImage(data: data!)!)
```

I print self.imageArray, and it prints, so I know it's there- it's just not displaying for some reason. It was displaying when I was manually setting the images in the array.

**Here is the full relevant code**

```
import UIKit

class OpenView: UIViewController {

// Scroll view because I'm going to have multiple images
 @IBOutlet weak var imageScrollView: UIScrollView!

// Receiving the string url for the image
 var fullReceievingImageString: String? = ""

// Establishing the Array
 var imageArray = [UIImage]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

// Convert the url to an image
    if let imageUrl = fullReceievingImageString {
        let url = URL(string: imageUrl)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

// Apply the image to the array
                self.imageArray.append(UIImage(data: data!)!)
                print(self.imageArray)

            }
            }.resume()
    }


// Establish the image view(s)
    for i in 0..<imageArray.count {

        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = imageArray[i]
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.imageScrollView.frame.width, height: self.imageScrollView.frame.height)

        imageScrollView.contentSize.width = imageScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
        imageScrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    }        
}
}
```

Comment: Thinks you have to research more about asynchronous task and closure, the code after `.resume()` basically run before the code inside `URLSession.shared.dataTask` finished so it won't show anything

Answer (score 0):

URLSession has Time delay,when you display the view imageArr there is nothing at that time,you can show as this:

```
 import UIKit

    class OpenView: UIViewController {

        // Scroll view because I'm going to have multiple images
        @IBOutlet weak var imageScrollView: UIScrollView!

        // Receiving the string url for the image
        var fullReceievingImageString: String? = ""

        // Establishing the Array
        var imageArray = [UIImage]()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            // Convert the url to an image
            if let imageUrl = fullReceievingImageString {
                let url = URL(string: imageUrl)
                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print(error!)
                        return
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        // Apply the image to the array
                        self.imageArray.append(UIImage(data: data!)!)
                        print(self.imageArray)
                        self.initSubView()

                    }
                    }.resume()
            }



        }
 private func initSubView(){
        // Establish the image view(s)
        for i in 0..<imageArray.count {

            let imageView = UIImageView()
            imageView.image = imageArray[i]
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.imageScrollView.frame.width, height: self.imageScrollView.frame.height)

            imageScrollView.contentSize.width = imageScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
            imageScrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        }
    }

   }
```

Comment: It still showed nothing, BUT, you gave me the idea to put the 'establish the image view' code inside the 'apply image to the array' bracket, and it worked. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I im sorry for not checking it seriously. There is another error,CGSize is a struct,so you can`t change like this : imageScrollView.contentSize.width = imageScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1) .      Here is the right way: imageScrollView.contentSize = CGSize.init(width: imageScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1), height: imageScrollView.frame.height)